# Use double quote then curly brace in powershell -Command

Tags: powershell, escaping, brackets

There are a couple questions related to this on here but they specifically address Write-Host. I want to run something like

```
powershell.exe -Command "'example.exe' /f`"`{GUID`}`""
```

Only it fails with the error

```
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At line:1 char:396
+ $mypid=(get-process EXEName*).id;wait-process -id $mypid;
& `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}\Target.exe`
/s /ig``{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`}` /instance=1  /f3`C:\Recordings`
/f4`uninstall-log.txt` /f1`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\`{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`}\setup.iss`
/f2`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\`{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`}\setup.log` /removeonly <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseBraceToken:TokenId) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace
```

I have other strings starting with `"` and containing `{}` (like `/f"C:\Folder\{GUID}\program.exe"` and these don't cause any trouble. It's only my argument where the curly braces are adjacent to the double quotes:

```
/ig`"`{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`}`"
```

In the error message, it may or may not be noteworthy that all the double quotes are gone so my /ig argument is left with two backticks. I believe my version is 2.0. Here is my actual (modified) command:

```
powershell -Command "$mypid=(get-process EXEName*).id;wait-process -id
$mypid;& 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-
XXXXXXXXXXXX}\Target.exe' /s /ig`"`{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-
XXXXXXXXXXXX`}`" /instance=1  /f3`"C:\Recordings`" /f4`"uninstall-log.txt`"
/f1`"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\`{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-
XXXXXXXXXXXX`}\setup.iss`" 
/f2`"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\`{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-
XXXXXXXXXXXX`}\setup.log`" /removeonly"
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? I don't know why it would be invalid. Thank you!

Comment: Why is there a double-quote after the /f?  You've delimited the string `"'example.exe' /f"` but {GUID} is not delimited by quotes.

Comment: @TonyHinkle I believe the double quotes are expected by example.exe. Removing them results in the powershell error `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-
XXXXXXXXXXXX}\Target.exe /s` is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using the -Command parameter for anything other than a simple script you will run into issues where characters such as curly braces and quotes will be misinterpritted by the command prompt before the are they are passed to Powershell. You could could tie yourself in knots by adding several layers of escaping or there is a simplier way - use the -EncodedCommand parametter instead.

For the EncodedCommand you just need to Base64 encode your command which you can do with the following Powershell script:

```
$command = @'
  # Enter your commands containg curly braces and quotes here
  # As long as you like  
'@
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes) | clip.exe
```

This will copy the encoded command to the clipboard, then all you need to do to use your command is type:

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand
```

.. and then paste in your command so that you end up with something like the following:

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand IAAgACMAIABFAG4AdABlAHIAIAB5AG8AdQByACAAcwBjAHIAaQBwAHQAIABjAG8AbgB0AGEAaQBuAGcAIABjAHUAcgBsAHkAIABiAHIAYQBjAGUAcwAgAGEAbgBkACAAcQB1AG8AdABlAHMACgAgACAAIwAgAEEAcwAgAGwAbwBuAGcAIABhAHMAIAB5AG8AdQAgAGwAaQBrAGUAIAAgAA==
```

You now have something that is command prompt safe.